# Migrate .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, .net-5, .net-4.8

Recently Microsoft has release .NET 5. If we want to upgrade .NET Framework 4.8 to .net 5 then how can we accomplish this task.

Please Note :

1. I had already upgrade Visual Studio 18.2 with all latest
   component and .net Framework 5. But in project property .net
   5 is not displayed.
2. My application is in .net Framework not in .net core.

***Update Feb 02, 2021***
Same Question I had posted on Microsoft Forum and luckily they replied very positively.

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/net-framework-48-upgrade-to-net-5/1269991?from=email&viewtype=all#T-ND1352565

**Update August 2021**

Message from Microsoft

We’ll continue to make the .NET Upgrade Assistant better through previews that will coming out in the GitHub repo. You can find it here: https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant

**Update May 2023**
one more link I found. It may helpful

https://procodeguide.com/dotnet/migrate-net-framework-to-net-core/

**Update Nov 2023**

***Require Visual Studio 17.6 or Later***

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.upgradeassistant

Download Microsoft .NET Upgrade Assistant which support to

.NET Upgrade Assistant (Preview)
The goal of this extension is to assist in upgrading your .NET applications to the latest versions of .NET. After installing the extension, you can right-click in Solution Explorer on the project you want to upgrade, choose “Upgrade” and follow the steps.

See the Upgrade Assistant blog post for more information.

[image]

Supported .NET upgrades:

.NET Framework to .NET 6+ (including .NET 8.0 Preview)

.NET Core to .NET 6+ (including .NET 8.0 Preview)

Any .NET version to .NET 6+ (including .NET 8.0 Preview) that is higher than the current version

Azure Functions v1, v2, v3 to v4 isolated (targeting net6.0 or net7.0)
Xamarin.Forms to MAUI

Note: For Xamarin->MAUI .xaml file transformations the Upgrade Assistant includes basic namespace replacements. More comprehensive .xaml file transformations require Visual Studio 17.6.

Supported project types:

1. ASP.NET
2. Azure Functions
3. WPF
4. WinForms
5. Class libraries
6. Console
7. Xamarin.Forms
8. .NET
9. MAUI
10. UWP

Happy upgrading!

Comment: Please keep in mind that there are a lot of major versions between .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET Core 5: .NET Core 1, .NET Core 2, .NET Core 3, .NET Core 5. You can't just switch to .NET Core: project files are different, package references defined differently. You need to go through the migration process following the official guides. But if you use 3rd-party libs, they can be incompatible with .NET Core / .NET Standard.

Comment: yes you are right, Not Working, 3rd-party libs are incompatible. Some microsoft libs are also incompatible.

Comment: You should download .Net 5 from the below link. Like other versions it does not appear.
For migration of .net framework 4.8 to .net 5 is not possible right now. .net 5 is under .net core versions. In the future it will most likely be migrated. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: What do you mean on Visual Studio 18.2? I don't know such VS version. The latest VS version (VS 2022) has currently the version number 17.0.5. There is however a version 18.2 of MS SQL Server Management Studio, that does not make sense in this context.

Answer (score 10):

You didn't mention what's the type of your project. But in general, you should follow the official docs. For example, for winforms projects, see [How to migrate a Windows Forms desktop app to .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-5.0).

Most likely, as the first thing, you will need to edit your project file manually and change it to the SDK style, as described in the article above:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
   ...
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Not Working,  3rd-party libs are incompatible

Comment: Some microsoft libs are also incompatible.

Answer (score 8):

you can use [.NET Upgrade Assistant tool](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/upgrade-assistant) released by Microsoft. This tool will easily convert your .net framework project to .net5.

Comment: Will it work if the application is .net 5 and the platform is 4.8 .net framework?

Comment: For More detail, please navigate to : https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/net-framework-48-upgrade-to-net-5/1269991?from=email&viewtype=all#T-ND1352565

Comment: https://medium.com/@dumindudesilva/migrate-from-the-net-framework-to-net-5-5aef306d10f5

Answer (score 6):

.NET 5 is the evolution of .NET core. So it is not a trivial change.
Firstly, you need to have Visual Studio 2019 (v16.8) (make sure that include .NET in the installation).
Second, you need to review if all your NuGet packages and libraries support this (and update it or look for a replacement).
Additionally you can take a look if any of the breaking changes affect you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0.
Keep in mind that .NET 5 is not an LTS, meaning that it will not be supported when .NET 6 comes out.

Depending on your architecture (layers of separations), how big is your solution and if you are using .NET standard for libraries, will depend on the effort you need to do (you might also need to do some refactoring). Anyhow you should plan this thoroughly since is not a trivial migration.