# Migrating from ASP.NET 4.0 to DOT NET CORE

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, vb.net-to-c#

We have a big ASP.NET application with VB.Net Framework 4.0.
We want to migrate to .NET 6
Is it better to first migrate to 4.8 then to .NET or directly from .NET Framework 4.0 to .NET 6.0 ?

Is it preferable to migrate, in the same time, or in a separate step, from VB.NET to C# ?

Comment: It all depends on the time you have. But it seems most of the documentation online is based on migrating from 4.8 upwards.  You might want to try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65017865/migrate-net-framework-4-8-to-net-5

Comment: My personal opinion also would be to change everything to C#. That will make everyday way easier and also staying up to date. VB won't be developed going forward, so switching to C# will have a lot of gains in the future than the current Pains you may think of.

Comment: Well, you can't use asp.net webforms with .net core. So, that means a big re-write, and you have to ask for what benefit? I mean, they JUST updated the web forms designer last year for vs2022, and it is a BIG update. This update for web forms is big news, and is NOT for MVC, and can't be used with MVC, but can be with web forms: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/design-your-web-forms-apps-with-web-live-preview-in-visual-studio-2022/